# $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are indeterminates over $F$ & $s_1,\dots,s_n$ be the symmetric functions of$x_i$. Show $[f(x_1,\dots,n_n):F(s_1,\dots,s_n)]=n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Question: Suppose $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are inderterminates over a field $F$ and $s_1,\dots,s_n$ be the elementary symmetric functions of the $x_i$, respectively.  Show $[F(x_1,\dots,x_n):F(s_1,\dots,s_n)]=n!$

I came across this problem dealing with solvability by radicals, but I am not quite sure how to even begin.   I believe, if I am not mistaken, that the elementary symmetric function, $s_n=x_1+\cdots+x_n$, but I suppose I am just not seeing how any of this stuff comes into play here.  I wish I had more thoughts on the topic, but that's why I am turning here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K=F(s_1,\ldots ,s_n)$ then $$[K(x_1):K]=n$$
Because $x_1$ is the solution to an irreducible equation of degree $n$.
Now we reduce to the case of $n-1$ by noting that
$K(x_1)=F(t_1,\ldots ,t_{n-1})$ where $t_i$ are the elementary symmetric functions in $x_2,\ldots , x_n$
and use induction.

Comment: If you follow the structure of this proof, can you conclude that $\{ x_1^{i_1} x_2^{i_2} \cdots x_{n-1}^{i_{n-1}} \mid i_1 < n, i_2 < n-1, \ldots, i_{n-1} < 2 \}$ forms a basis for the field extension?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, that seems reasonable.